# How Listview Item Eval field does not updated in an updatePanel?

Tags: updatepanel, postback, listviewitem

I have a list view to show products with prices. I put an updatePanel in ItemTemplate.
When I Click the button in contentTemplate, the Eval fields do not update, By definition the
update panel do a partial post back but it does not reflect database changes.

```
         <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:ImageButton ID="productPic" runat="server" Height="270" Width="202" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />

             <asp:Table ID="ColorTable" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:Table>
             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
             <asp:Literal ID="LitProductId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>' EnableViewState="true"></asp:Literal>
             <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' Font-Size="8"
                                    Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="tahoma" />
             <br />
             <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price","{0:0,0}") %>' Font-Size="8" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="tahoma"
                                    Font-Strikeout='<%# Eval("DiscountedPrice")!=DBNull.Value %>' />
             <br />
             <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DiscountedPrice","{0:0,0}") %>' Font-Size="10" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="tahoma" ForeColor="Red"
                                    Visible='<%# Eval("DiscountedPrice")!=DBNull.Value %>' />
             <br />
     </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
 <br />
  </td>
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
If you want to use update panel inside a listview, you should bind the data source in code - page load.

```
ListView1.DataSource = new ProductFacade().GetCat3ProductListSpec(cat3Id);
ListView1.DataBind();
```

When you use sqlDataSource attribute, the update panel does not function as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are dynamically adding them in. When you post back, it loses that state and if you aren't adding them back in at that point (i.e. saving them to viewstate and adding them back in on load), it no longer knows they exist.

Comment: Ok, in which event should I create my buttons again? Actually they are in ItemDataBound event but it does not run on updatepanel postback.

Comment: Isn't it that updatePanel updates the fields automatically? or should I do it by code?